# C programming %d { printf("%d"); }

Tags: c, printf

**The program is as follows:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[7]={1,2,3,4};
   printf("%d%d%d%d%d",(*a),*(&*a),a[*a*0],*a);
   return 0;
}
```

The Output on codepad.org is as follows:
11110

The Output on ideone.com is as follows:
1111-1074526944  *where -1074526944 keeps varying every execution*

I executed it on my personal gcc output is: 11110 *i dont have the latest gcc*

In the `printf();` statement i am not concerned about the first four `%d`'s because its totally obvious.
its the *fifth* `%d` i am concerned about. Why does it give such an output?

Comment: notice that you're only passing *4* arguments past the format string, which includes *5* format specifiers.

Comment: It invokes _undefined behaviour_, so anything could happen.

Answer (score 9):

It tries to access whatever data happened to be on the stack of the call to printf() at the offset where a supposed "fifth parameter" would be, which your call to the function obviously has not provided.

- To get a feel for it, learn how to write *variadic functions*.
- To really understand it, you'd have to learn assembly.
- To avoid such programming mistakes, use the `-Wall` parameter, which would have told you:

> ```
> $ gcc -Wall main.c 
> main.c: In function ‘main’:
> main.c:5:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat]
> ```